# Pass object to a selector

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I use this code to detect a long pressed element:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
// some stuff 

if let labelCell = model as? TTTLabelCell{
labelCell.delegate = self
labelCell.textLabel.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRec)
  }
}
```

This is the gesture recognizer

```
longPressRec.addTarget(self, action:#selector(labelLongPressed))
```

And this is the selector

```
   func labelLongPressed(){
        print("Label Long pressed")
   //  labelCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
```

What I want to achieve, as commented on the code, is to pass the selected object (labelCell) to the selector labelLongPressed() which will allow me to change some attributes. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: use this `longPressRec.addTarget(self, action:#selector(labelLongPressed:))`

Comment: @dahiya_boy, the OP is asking to pass a table cell. That code only passes the long press recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

change func as below :

```
func labelLongPressed(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("Label Long pressed")
        let labelCell: TTTLabelCell = sender.view // track as per your view hierarchy
         labelCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd suggest adding the gesture recognizer to the cell itself rather than to the text label. This gives the user a bigger tap area, and makes it easier to reference the cell when the long press is recognized.

```
labelCell.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRec)
```

Add an argument to your gesture action, to pass the gesture recognizer. Then we can use the recogniser's view, to get a reference to the cell — since we are adding the gesture recogniser directly to the cell.

```
func labelLongPressed(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    guard recognizer.state == .began else { return }

    print("Label Long press began!")

    if let labelCell = recognizer.view as? TTTLabelCell {
        labelCell.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
}
```

Finally, when adding the target to the Gesture Recognizer, update the Selector to match our function signature.

```
longPressRec.addTarget(self, action:#selector(labelLongPressed(_:)))
```